# Excel data extraction issue

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

Creating a tracking sheet for my investments. I have an API installed that gives live raw market data but not my specific investments. I'm wanting to bring in a column that shows how the assets are performing in a 24 hr period (this data is in sheet2). The data in sheet 2 is constantly changing as it is sorted in Market Cap so depending on how the assets are performing on a given day the data is constantly changing. My list of investments are in sheet 1 and I'm wanting to perform a formula that will be able to grab the correct data from sheet2 and implement it into the correct column in sheet1.

An example:

I want to bring the 24hr % performance from sheet 2 (where the raw data is) of the stock 'AAPL', and insert it next to Sheet1 where I track my investments by the Symbol of the stock: AAPL

For the formula below:

C6 is where I store the SYMBOL (ie "AAPL").

latest[Column1.symbol] is the column in the referred sheet2 to match the symbol.

latest[Column1.quote.USD.percent_change_24h] is the raw data for the 24hr % change of the stock.

I thought it'd be something like :

```
=IF(ISTEXT(C6),FIND("AAPL",latest[Column1.symbol])(latest[Column1.quote.USD.percent_change_24h]),(""))
```

Which is apparently a failed formula.

Someone commented on a previous post this: "Do a column that shows the 24 hr progress then use vlookup() or index() and match() to return the value" - I still can't figure the correct formula

My response was: "On sheet 1 I have a 24hr % change but how do I grab the data from sheet2. The formula I've done now is: `=IF(ISTEXT(C6),VLOOKUP("AAPL",latest[#All],latest[Column1.symbol],FALSE))` but you may notice it doesn't have any instruction to grab the right data. That formula returns the N/A error. For reference, the data I need to grab is from column 'F' of sheet 2."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel - grabbing specific data from sheet2 depending on a certain cell in sheet1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68701474/excel-grabbing-specific-data-from-sheet2-depending-on-a-certain-cell-in-sheet1)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out the IEX cloud API at [IEX Excel How To](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#excel-how-to)

Once you register and receive a free key, you can download real-time data. For example, to retrieve the APPLE data, you would use `WEBSERVICE("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/aapl/quote/latestPrice?token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE")` with your token.

If you can attach a copy of your spreadsheet, I might be able to help further. [Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnOjaIItfTHenyoET8dQ42or985F?e=HQZVfd) is a link to an IEX template that I made a few changes to. Just add your token for the updated data. I added columns for changePercent, open, close, high, low, and volume.  Here is a sample of the raw data that shows the other variables you can pull data for.

```
{"symbol":"AAPL",
"companyName":"Apple Inc",
"primaryExchange":"NASDAQ/NGS (GLOBAL SELECT MARKET)",
"calculationPrice":"close","open":146.27,
"openTime":1628256600564,"openSource":"official",
"close":146.14,"closeTime":1628280000832,
"closeSource":"official",
"high":147.11,
"highTime":1628280000018,
"highSource":"15 minute delayed price",
"low":145.63,
"lowTime":1628276124261,
"lowSource":"15 minute delayed price",
"latestPrice":146.14,
"latestSource":"Close",
"latestTime":"August 6, 2021","
latestUpdate":1628280000832,
"latestVolume":54126458,
"iexRealtimePrice":null,
"iexRealtimeSize":null,
"iexLastUpdated":null,
"delayedPrice":146.14,
"delayedPriceTime":1628279999937,
"oddLotDelayedPrice":146.035,
"oddLotDelayedPriceTime":1628279993919,
"extendedPrice":145.96,
"extendedChange":-0.18,
"extendedChangePercent":-0.00123,
"extendedPriceTime":1628294398800,
"previousClose":146.84,
"previousVolume":46397674,
"change":-0.7,
"changePercent":-0.00477,
"volume":54126458,
"iexMarketPercent":null,
"iexVolume":null,
"avgTotalVolume":82684813,
"iexBidPrice":null,
"iexBidSize":null,
"iexAskPrice":null,
"iexAskSize":null,
"iexOpen":146.11,
"iexOpenTime":1628279999601,
"iexClose":146.11,
"iexCloseTime":1628279999601,
"marketCap":2415718459240,
"peRatio":28.65,
"week52High":149.78,
"week52Low":102.44,
"ytdChange":0.10176860278111127,
"lastTradeTime":1628279999970,
"currency":"USD",
"isUSMarketOpen":false}
```

To add new fields to the spreadsheet use the formula: `=WEBSERVICE(CONCATENATE($B$2,$A5,"/quote/",J$4,"?token=",$B$1))`
but change the J$4 to the cell containing the field name from the quote.